# Eclipse and PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, installation, pydev, versions

I want to start using Eclipse with the PyDev plugin, as recommended by [this poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python/81621#81621). The [PyDev download page](http://pydev.org/download.html) says I need Eclipse (3.2 to 3.5) and that I can use the Platform Runtime Binary.

1. Can I also use Eclipse 3.5.2 (or maybe even 3.6) instead of 3.5?
2. Where can I find the Platform Runtime Binary? I'm a little bit lost in the [Eclipse download pages](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

Comment: The Platform Runtime Binary is found here http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6-201006080911/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyDev works great with Eclipse 3.6. I'd download the [Java Edition](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliosr), which is pretty minimal (as far as Eclipse can be minimal). Then you can use the brand new built-in marketplace to install PyDev. No need to look up the update-URL. You find the marketplace under "Help > Eclipse Marketplace..." (why they put the market place in the help menu is beyond me...).

Note that if you download the Eclipse Classic edition, you won't get the marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I use eclipse 3.5.2 with pydev plugin and it works great. Install the pydev plugin by opening up Help / Install New Software and putting in "Pydev - http://pydev.org/updates" into the Work with field. Then follow on the installation procedure. After pydev is installed make sure that you put the python interpreter into the window / preferences /pydev / Interpreter - python page

Answer (score 0):

> Can I also use Eclipse 3.5.2 (or maybe
>   even 3.6) instead of 3.5?

<s>Try and find out. :)</s>
[Yes.](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/114)

> Where can I find the Platform Runtime
>   Binary? I'm a little bit lost in the
>   Eclipse download pages.

You won't need it.

Comment: I would like to use the Platform Runtime Binary because it apparently is the smallest Eclipse intaller. I don't need C/C++ or Java, I only use Eclipse for Python.